# Fetch data with getJSONArray in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

I'm trying to fetch some data from json. I made function to fetch JSON.

My code:

```
val obj = JSONObject(getJSONFromAssets()!!)

val userArray = obj.getJSONObject("user_id")
```

My code to fetchAssets:

```
private fun getJSONFromAssets(): String ?{
        var json: String? = null
        val charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8

        try{
            val jsonFile = assets.open(K.json.jsonFileName)
            val size = jsonFile.available()
            val buffer = ByteArray(size)

            jsonFile.read(buffer)
            jsonFile.close()
            json = String(buffer, charset)
        }
        catch (ex: IOException){
            ex.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }

        return json
    }
```

JSON File:

```
{
  "user_id": "1",
  "acounts": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "AccountNumber": "HR123456789012345678901",
      "amount": "2.523,00",
      "currency": "USD",
      "transactions":
```

UserModelClass:

```
data class UserModelClass (
    val user_id:String,
    val accounts: List<AccountsList>
)
```

Problem is that I have user ID and then accounts where I can loop easy.

Error: Failed to open file, no such file or directory.
Value 1 at user_id of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: What is AccountsList?

Comment: An array that has other variables (id, amount, currency etc.)